# Order of execution in Java

Tags: java, order-of-execution

I am trying to understand [this example from Thinking in Java](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ309_009.htm):

```
package c07;
import com.bruceeckel.simpletest.*;

class Meal {
    Meal() { System.out.println("Meal()"); }
}

class Bread {
    Bread() { System.out.println("Bread()"); }
}

class Cheese {
    Cheese() { System.out.println("Cheese()"); }
}

class Lettuce {
    Lettuce() { System.out.println("Lettuce()"); }
}

class Lunch extends Meal {
    Lunch() { System.out.println("Lunch()"); }
}

class PortableLunch extends Lunch {
    PortableLunch() { System.out.println("PortableLunch()");}
}

public class Sandwich extends PortableLunch {
    private static Test monitor = new Test();
    private Bread b = new Bread();
    private Cheese c = new Cheese();
    private Lettuce l = new Lettuce();

    public Sandwich() {
        System.out.println("Sandwich()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sandwich();
        monitor.expect(new String[] {
          "Meal()",
          "Lunch()",
          "PortableLunch()",
          "Bread()",
          "Cheese()",
          "Lettuce()",
          "Sandwich()"
        });
    }
}
```

As I understand from Java Language Specification, the order of execution begins by loading the class containing the main method. Then all the statics and member variables of this class must be initialized (before which all the member variables of the superclasses must be intialized, although there are none of those in this case).

So I thought `b`, `c`, `l` would be initialized before `main` starts executing. That does not seem to be the case from the output though. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `b` and `c` are *instance* variables.

There's no automatic instantiation of the class containing `main`. Only *static* variables are initialized. It's just as if some outside caller wrote:

```
Sandwich.main(args);
```

So when you wrote:

> Then all the statics and member variables of this class must be initialized

... that was wrong. Only the static variables are initialized - just as normal.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the answer. This is what I read in the JLS (it says all class variables are initialized not just statics): In our continuing example, the Java virtual machine is still trying to execute the
method main of class Test. This is permitted only if the class has been initialized
(§12.4.1).
Initialization consists of execution of any class variable initializers and static
initializers of the class Test, in textual order. But before Test can be initialized,
its direct superclass must be initialized, as well as the direct superclass of its direct
superclass, and so on, recursively.

Comment: "class variable" == "static variable". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3 "A class variable is a field declared using the keyword static within a class declaration (§8.3.1.1), or with or without the keyword static within an interface declaration (§9.3)."

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Why does it say "class variable initializers and static initializers" if "class variable" == "static variable"?

Comment: Even earlier in the book, the author says "variables are initialized before any methods can be called—even the constructor" and there are no statics in the example here: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ306_014.htm

Comment: @Jin: That's in the context of *calling a constructor*.

Comment: @Jin: The JLS refers to static variables as "class variables". Most people just call them static variables, but the point is that the term "class variables" does *not* include instance variables. Note that static initializers are different to class variable initializers. They're blocks like this: `static { /* code here */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

The example output is correct. Here are the important rules:

- when the class is created, the constructor of the super class has to be called first. This bubbles up to `Object` class
- before the constructor is called, member variable initialization is called.

No `static`s are involved in this example, except the technical `monitor`.

Answer (score 0):

[JLS # 12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)

A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:

- T is a class and an instance of T is created.
- T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
- A static field declared by T is assigned.
- A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
  variable (§4.12.4).
- T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10)
  lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

[JLS # 12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

> Whenever a new class instance is created, memory space is allocated for it with room for all the instance variables declared in the class type and all the instance variables declared in each superclass of the class type, including all the instance variables that may be hidden (§8.3).